# Почему возникает ошибка в конструкторе компоненты?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь создать компоненту меню. Поступающий объект может иметь разную вложенность `groups`(в тестовом объекте 3 увроня). При загрузке страницы я пытаюсь вызвать метод, который генерирует  текущие итемы ( нужно отрисовать 2 уровня: первый и второй, который будет являться подуровнем), но он ругается на 
`menu_items    : this.getMenuItems(this.state.items)`;

Пишет:

```
Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Код компоненты:

```
class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            level_counter : 0,
            items         : [
            {
                'id' : 1,
                'title' : 'Dashboard',
                'groups' : [
                    {
                        'id' : 2,
                        'title' : ' Group 1',
                        'groups' : [],                  
                    },
                    {
                        'id' : 3,
                        'title' : 'Measure Group 2',
                        'groups' : [
                            {
                                'id' : 4,
                                'title' : 'Group 4',
                                'groups' : [],
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        menu_items    : this.getMenuItems(this.state.items),
        };

    }


    render() {
        let { items,menu_items } = this.state;

        console.log(this.state.items)
        return (
            <div className='menu-container'>
                <ul className='menuItems-list'>
                    <li className='menuItem'>
                        <a>
                            <Icon className='menuItem-iconBack' name='caret left' size='small'/> Back
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {menu_items}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    getMenuItems = ( items ) => {
        let { menu_items } = this.state;

        for(let group in  items) {
            menu_items.push(
                <MenuItem         key     = {items[group].id}
                                  item    = {items[group]}
                                  onClick = { this.menuItemClick }
                />
            );
            if (items[group].groups.length > 0 && this.state.level_counter != 0) {
                this.setState({level_counter: this.state.level_counter + 1})
                this.getMenuItems(items[group].groups)
            }
        }
        return menu_items;
    };

    menuItemClick = itemId => {
        let { items } = this.state;
        this.setState({level_counter: 0});
        this.getCurrentMenuLevel( items, itemId);
    };

    getCurrentMenuLevel = ( items,itemId ) => {

        for(let item in items){
            if (items[item].id != itemId ) {
                this.getCurrentMenuLevel ( items[item].groups,itemId);
            } else {
                this.getMenuItems (items[item].groups);
            }
        }
    };

}


export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы в переменной this.state пытаетесь присвоить значение, которое содержить ссылку на this.state, которая в момент присваивания равно undefined. Нужно удалить menu_items из state

```
    this.state = {
        level_counter: 0,
        items: [{
            'id': 1,
            'title': 'Dashboard',
            'groups': [{
                    'id': 2,
                    'title': ' Group 1',
                    'groups': [],
                },
                {
                    'id': 3,
                    'title': 'Measure Group 2',
                    'groups': [{
                        'id': 4,
                        'title': 'Group 4',
                        'groups': [],
                    }],
                }
            ]
        }],
    };
```

Comment: рекомендую пользоваться отладчиком (дебагером) для определения какая переменная чему равняется в рантайме